# What are some sources of error in the preparation of a standard solution (of sodium carbonate) and a titration (determining the concentration of HCl)?

Tags: acid-base, titration

When preparing  a standard solution of sodium carbonate, what are some sources of error?
Also, when conducting a titration, what are some errors involved when determining the concentration of hydrochloric acid?
Thank you

Comment: This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most errors of standardization come from weighing the solid ($\ce{Na2CO3}$) or from measuring the liquid added in the dilution of $\ce{HCl}$. In theory you could do the necessary calculations and take the time needed to weigh out the solid/liquid you can create solutions that are incredibly accurate that will be very near the target molarity. As far as standardizations go imprecision of the equipment is going to be the biggest drawback, though ensuring the sodium carbonate is throughly dried could be another source of error.